# Macro to clean Data from Blank using Autofilter with headers name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a Macro to clean Dataset by deleting blank cells  using an Autofilter method with a header instead of a column number. As you can see. There is no Cells number in this Macro and there will not. Everything has to be automatic. That is the idea.

I wrote 90% of the code. I arrived at the water source but I can not drink.

I got the error for the last line.

> Error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed.

Here is the code:

```vb
Sub DeleteBlank()

Dim WrkS As Worksheet, LsC As Range, FsC As Range, Tab As Range
Dim LsH As Range, RNbr As Long, CNbr As Long, HdrRow As Range, FltCol As Variant


Set WrkS = Worksheets("data")

' Last cells 

Set LsC = Cells(Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row, _
  Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

' First cells 

Set FsC = Cells(Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).row, _
  Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

FsC.Activate

RNbr = ActiveCell.row

LsC.Activate

CNbr = ActiveCell.Column

'to set the last header 

Set LsH = Cells(RNbr, CNbr)

' to set the header Row

Set HdrRow = Range(FsC, LsH)

Set Tab = WrkS.UsedRAnge  

' to get the Column name in which I have to delete all blank 

With HdrRow

FltCol = .Find(what:="name", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

End With

' the problem is below 
' Error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed.
WrkS.Tab.AutoFilter Field:=FltCol, Criteria1:="="

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I couldn't declare a variable called "Tab". Since it was already defined as a range on WrKS you don't need the sheet reference on the AF line. Also, when using Find best to check the value is found to avoid errors. You should really use sheet references everywhere (or activate the sheet at the beginning).

```
Sub DeleteBlank()

Dim WrkS As Worksheet, LsC As Range, FsC As Range, Tab1 As Range
Dim LsH As Range, RNbr As Long, CNbr As Long, HdrRow As Range, FltCol As Variant

Set WrkS = Worksheets("data")

Set LsC = Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set FsC = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not FsC Is Nothing Then
    If Not LsC Is Nothing Then
        RNbr = FsC.Row
        CNbr = LsC.Column
        Set LsH = Cells(RNbr, CNbr)
        Set HdrRow = Range(FsC, LsH)
        Set Tab1 = WrkS.UsedRange
        FltCol = HdrRow.Find(what:="name", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        Tab1.AutoFilter Field:=FltCol, Criteria1:="="
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can shorten it down to this

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteBlank()

    With Worksheets("data").UsedRange ' reference relevant worksheet "usedrange"
        With Intersect(.Rows(1).Find(what:="name", LookAt:=xlWhole).EntireColumn, .Cells) 'reference its column whose top cell content is "name"
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" 'filter referenced column blank cells
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete ' if any filtered cells other than first row (header) then delete their entire row
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```